# Referencing a defined html variable in JS

Tags: javascript, html

My index.php page includes a config.php file, which returns an array that I have defined some variables in by using "define('var1' , 10)".

I am trying to validate my forms input, but I can't figure out how I can reference var1 from within the JS function. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo it to a javascript variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var var1JS = "<?php echo $var1; ?>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure I am full understanding without seeing the code but, you could echo the variable from the PHP array in the JS function (as above answer).

Or Echo the entire JS query:

```
$y = count($PHPdata_array);

echo "function exampleFunction() {";
echo "var ArrayName = [";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $y; $i+=2) {
echo "{" . $PHPdata_array[$i] . "," . $PHPdata_array[$i-1] . "},";
}
echo "];";
```